# Testing a form submission handler with Jasmine jQuery

Tags: jquery, forms, jasmine

I have a form which has a handler attached to the submit event, like this:

```
$('#myForm').bind('submit', $.proxy(this, 'form_onSubmit'));
```

I can't work out how to test this line of code to ensure that when the form is submitted, it uses the correct event handler. For example, this doesn't work as the page keeps submitting itself in an infinite loop:

```
describe('Submitting the form', function() {
    it ('Uses the correct event handler', function() {
        spyOn(myConstructor, 'form_onSubmit');
        $('#myForm').trigger('submit');
        expect(myConstructor.form_onSubmit).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

I've also been trying to use:

```
expect($('#myForm')).toHandleWith('submit', myConstructor.form_onSubmit);
```

But as I haven't been able to find a working example of this anywhere, I'm sure I'm using it incorrectly (Jasmine is throwing the error "Cannot read property 'submit' of undefined" where undefined is this.actual.data("events")).

Can anyone please help? I've been at it for hours! Thanks.

Comment: hmmm... Does `triggerHandler('submit')` also cause the page to postback?

Comment: That does prevent the postback from occurring (never used that before - thanks!) but unfortunately the test still fails as Jasmine thinks myConstructor.form_onSubmit doesn't get called. (Although if I put a breakpoint in the code it does)

Answer (score 8):

I am using Jasmine jQuery to spy on the event.

https://github.com/velesin/jasmine-jquery#event-spies

Also I am mocking the form using a fixture.

On the form itself (in the fixture) I set the action to "javascript:void(0)" to prevent the form submission from happening.

```
<form class="js-game-form" action="javascript:void(0)">
</form>
```

For the test

```
describe("#submitForm", function(){
    it("should submit the form when you press one of the update buttons", function(){
      var spyEvent = spyOnEvent(formSelector, 'submit');
      $(updateButtonSelector).trigger("click");
      expect(spyEvent).toHaveBeenTriggered();
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this, especially setting the action of the form to do nothing is crucial here!

Comment: `javascript:void(0)` FTW.  My karma test runner was reloading the page despite have set `onsubmit="return false;"`.